# Is Kestrel - IIS | Apache an ideal runtime host process over queue backed Windows services for microservices?

Tags: iis, .net-core, windows-services, microservices, soa

Message durability concerns aside for the moment, I'm afraid that, under load, web server runtimes aren't designed for long running processes that could invoke a few remote providers or DB calls per transaction. If I have IIS or Apache proxying traffic to the Kestrel hosted .Net Core app, are resources shared better or more efficiently than classic IIS .Net apps?

I'm wondering if I have to wait for a volume event to buckle our resource knees before we transition to queue backed services.

Answer (score 1):

No production grade server has any issue with being a long running process. The only thing that can happen are leaks. These servers are tested for leaks. When you send 100k requests per second for a few minutes even a one byte leak becomes obvious.

I'm not sure what you mean by sharing resources more efficiently. The server has fairly little performance impact on typical apps. Most apps actually do some work which overshadows the server overhead. The application code will always perform exactly the same way. Just the server overhead might be a little less or more.

So it does not really matter for throughput which server you use if your application does meaningful work on each request. If you just benchmark a `return "Hello World";` then you measure the framework overhead which likely does not matter much.

I recommend that you use the server type that is most convenient and productive to use.